# Cвойство класса типа текст и метод для возврата этого свойства

Tags: c++

Если нужно использовать текстовое поле в классе в private, и написать public метод для получения значения этого поля, как лучше сделать?
Сейчас я для хранения пытаюсь использовать`char* pole` либо `char pole[10];` Если я правильно понимаю, вернуть массив char нельзя, а как тогда быть?

```
#include <stdio.h>
class MyClass
{
  public:
    int getPole1()
    {
        return pole1;
    }
    void setPole1(int n)
    {
        pole1 = n;
    }
    //здесь должны быть аналогичные методы для поля pole2
  private:
    int pole1;
    char pole2[10];
};

int main()
{
    MyClass my;
    //здесь я должен установить значение pole2 и затем его получить
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, ставьте метки правильно. Во-первых, у вас тут точно не Си. Во-вторых, не надо ставить метки по принципу "все что есть в коде".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: В `c++` нет ни свойств, ни методов. Есть данные-члены и функции-члены.

Comment: @PavelMayorov объясните, пожалуйста, почему с++, а не с, если я не использую с++ библиотеки, а только stdio? мне собственно чистый си и нужно использовать, а не с++.

Comment: На "чистом Си" не существует никаких классов и методов.

Comment: Если вы пишите класс - это может быть только c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас учебное задание, то для передачи строки надо использовать тип `const char *` (он же `char const *`). Массив символов может неявно приводиться к этому типу данных.

Но хранить в классе строку в виде указателя - нельзя, ведь время жизни экземпляра класса и время жизни строки может и не совпадать. Поэтому в классе надо хранить массив символов, и при записи значения свойства надо копировать строку из параметра в массив либо в цикле, либо при помощи [`strncpy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xdsywd25.aspx).

Если же у вас реальная задача - то подключайте `<string>` и просто используйте `std::string`.

Comment: Указатель хранить можно, надо только им правильно управлять. Реализовать соответствующий обвес (правило трёх).

Answer (score 1):

Если критично именно `char*`, а не `string`, то я бы делал класс так:

```
class MyClass
{
  public:

    ....

    const char * getPole2() const { return pole2; }

    void setPole2(const char * p)
    {
        delete[] pole2;
        pole2 = (p) ? new char[strlen(p)+1] : nullptr;
        if (pole2) strcpy(pole2,p);
    }

    ~MyClass() { delete[] pole2; }

  private:
    int pole1;
    char * pole2 = 0;
};
```

Но применение члена типа `string` проще.

Answer (score 1):

Все попытки реализовать чтение и установку строкового типа данных, в качестве члена класса в конечном итоге приведут к созданию собственного аналога `std::string`. Поэтому не надо изобретать велосипед и наступать на грабли, а стоит воспользоваться стандартным, проверенным решением.

При этом, вкладывание в `MyClass` ещё и функционала строки приводит к супер-классу, который будет обслуживать и работу со строкой, и работу с целыми числам, а может и ещё с чем-то в будущем. Это усложнит дальнейшее использование и отладку такого класса. Поэтому всю работу со строками (даже если хочется сделать это самому без использования `std::string`) надо выносить в отдельный класс.

Если упомянутый член `pole2` должен всегда быть известного на момент компиляции размера (например, как у Вас в примере 10 символов), то вместо `std::string` логичнее использовать класс `std::array`. Геттеры и сеттеры в таком случае будут реализоваться элементарно, так же как и при использовании `std::string`, то оверхеда будет меньше.